# How can I transfer songs etc to iPod without access to iTunes account?

Tags: itunes, data-synchronization, ipod-touch

My stepdaughter has brought her iPod home with her. We would like to transfer some photos and songs from our computer onto her iPod, but her mother has it connected to her own iTunes account. Since she is unwilling to share the password, we can't do it via iTunes syncing.

I thought I would be able to do it by just dragging across but it seems not. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You have to manually manage the music and videos in order to do this.

You can manually manage music by:

1. Plug the iPod into your computer and open iTunes.
2. Under the Summary Tab, Select the "Manually Manage Music and Videos" checkbox.
3. You should now be able to drag songs and videos onto the iPod as you expected.
4. One other note: if you are on iTunes 11, after performing the actions above, go to the "On This iPhone" tab (the last tab), and use that to manually manage music and videos.